# Confusion between moment of area and moment of inertia

Tags: definition, moment-of-inertia

How to calculate the [second moment of area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area)? I have read that it's equal to [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia). Are they same? If they are same then why they have different formula?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area) suggests that moment of area is not the same as moment of inertia.

Moment of inertia allows for a varying mass density.  Second moment of area is purely about the shape of the object.   The two would be proportional to each other if the physical object whose moment of inertia is under consideration has a uniform mass density, and is a right cylinder.

Comment: Why they are represented by same symbol I